# iteration scope name in ng-repeat

Tags: angularjs

This is my controller

```
var i;

for (i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ) {
   $scope["items"+i].push({
      notification: item.notification,
      admin_id: item.admin_id,
      user_id: item.user_id,
      chat_time: item.chat_time
   })
}
```

This is my static scope in ng-repeat

```
 <ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in items1"></li>
  <li ng-repeat="x in items2"></li>
  <li ng-repeat="x in items3"></li>
 </ul>
```

How to make dynamic iteration scope variabel in ng-repeat in single ng-repeat like this

```
<ul>
  <li ng-repeat="x in items[i++]"> 
     <!-- generate from here-->
        <li ng-repeat="x in items1"></li>
        <li ng-repeat="x in items2"></li>
        <li ng-repeat="x in items3"></li> 
     <!-- to here -->
  </li>
</ul>
```

and it will display like my static scope

Thanks , appreciate ur help and comment

Comment: You need to change the data structure, It would be better if you share more controller code, What is `item` in `notification: item.notification`?

Comment: function getChannels(i){
        Pusher.subscribe( channelName[i] , 'event-' + channelName[i]  , function (item) {
       $scope["chats"+i].push({    notification: item.notification,
      admin_id: item.admin_id,
      user_id: item.user_id,
      chat_time: item.chat_time});
        });
      };

Comment: Use an array rather than three variables.

Comment: i see , thanks for ur comment btw

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to store all the different `arrays` in a new Array and then, you can loop it around as shown *(I have created a sample)*:

**JS:**

```
$scope.item1 = [ /* json array 1 */];

$scope.item2 = [ /* json array 2 */];

$scope.item3 = [ /* json array 3 */];

$scope.itemsList = [];
for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
  var varName = '$scope.item' + (i + 1);
  $scope.itemsList.push(eval(varName));
}
```

**HTML:**

```
<li ng-repeat="mainList in itemsList">
      <p ng-repeat="specificList in mainList">
        <span>Id: {{specificList.id}}</span>
        <br />
        <span>Name: {{specificList.name}}</span>
      </p>
</li>
```

Have a look at the [**demo**](https://jsfiddle.net/shashank2691/4kqa66qz/).

Comment: i got error like this http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.5/ngRepeat/dupes?p0=mainList%20in%20itemsList&p1=undefined%3Aundefined&p2=undefined

Comment: use as suggested - `track by $index` or show the demo link.

Comment: i'm finally got it , thanks man for ur code , it really help me out. GBU